# PHP - Convert a messy string to a useable one

Tags: php, regex, string, converters

I have a bunch of data from a football team that needs tidying up. Currently, it looks like this (for demonstration purposes, I've only included 3):

```
1   
Team One
9   7   1   1   31  13  18  22
2   
Team Two
9   6   2   1   25  21  4   19
3   
Team Three
9   4   3   2   26  18  8   14
```

For clarity, I'll deconstruct the first 3 lines:

```
1\t\n
Team One\n
9\t7\t1\t1\t31\t13\t18\t22
```

Notice how there is a tab and then a linebreak after the position of each team. Then, the team name on the next line, with just a linebreak. And then finally, all of the details about that team. Then the next team's stats start.

I need it to be converted to:

```
1,Team One,9,7,1,1,31,13,18,22
2,Team Two,9,6,2,1,25,21,4,19
3,Team Three,9,4,3,2,26,18,8,14
```

Each line starts with the team's position, then team name, then each stat -- all separated by commas.

I've attempted doing this with very little luck. I imagine some kind of fancy regex can do the trick, but I wouldn't know how... hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Have you heard about awk and its implementation gawk?

Comment: @PatrykZiemkowski Hadn't heard of it, will have a look!

Comment: It is designed exactly for problems like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$in = file("log.txt");
$out = fopen("php://output", "w");

foreach(array_chunk($in, 3) as $group) {
    $group = array_map("trim", $group);
    $group[2] = implode(",", str_getcsv($group[2], "\t"));
    fputcsv($out, $group);
}
```

Output

```
1,"Team One","9,7,1,1,31,13,18,22"
2,"Team Two","9,6,2,1,25,21,4,19"
3,"Team Three","9,4,3,2,26,18,8,14"
```

If you want empty enclosure then use

```
fputcsv($out, $group, ",", " ");
```

Output

```
1, Team  One , 9,7,1,1,31,13,18,22 
2, Team  Two , 9,6,2,1,25,21,4,19 
3, Team  Three , 9,4,3,2,26,18,8,14
```

Comment: Thanks! This gave me the best results!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $resultstr = array();
        foreach($Teams as $items){
        $resultstr[] = $items['Team One'];
    }
    $items = implode(", ",$resultstr);
    echo $items;
?>
```

something like that. You can edit it with your own data because you did not mention that in your question.